# Cannot publish Infopath form due to Invalid Form Template error

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath

I have deleted a list that the InfoPath form was DC to. I deleted the column and removed the DC from InfoPath as well, now I get an Invalid Form Template error. I have to fix this - how can I remove these references "under the hood" so I can publish?

the field was a lookup field called Products1.  I've deleted all refs to this field and still get the same error that the template is invalid. I've worked on this all day and now I am in unrecoverable state.

Answer (score 2):

Found it after 8 hours. it was a field reference in a default value of a hidden field. THANKS A LOT for making the debugging process so TERRIFIC InfoPath!!  (not)

Comment: Check your answer as answered :-)

Answer (score 0):

I know that my message far to late but hope someone will find it and fix his/her error.

Conflict is hidden between choicefield values that infopath sends to a list and values you set to a choicefield in list setting in browser. If values are the same - you ll 70% get an error. 
To avoid that error you should insert values manualy in field properties in infopath if you have already changed choicefield properties in browser.